Greenplum in Docker
I have a Docker container with Greenplum 5, I want to move data to a new container with Greenplum 6, when restoring with:
gunzip -c db.dump | psql 

The directory /var/lib/docker/overlay2/* is very swollen, although on /gpdata I have volume to disk.
docker run —-name gp6 -v /mnt/gpdata:/gpdata -p 5432:5432 greenplum6

I don't understand how to do this correctly, why data isn’t mapped to gpdata?
